# C++: Use queue as value of a map

Tags: c++

I want to know if it's proper to use another type of container, for example, queue, as value of a map. I declare a map like this: `map<string, queue<string>> id` . Is it a appropriate way to use map? Actually, my code are as follow.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <map>
#include <queue>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    map<string, queue<string>> m;

    char temp[1024];
    strcpy(temp, "hello world");

    m[temp].push(temp);

    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: Define "appropriate"

Comment: Yes you can use it that way

Comment: Is it proper to use it the way you describe? Sure, there are no limitations to that. Does it make sense to use a queue inside map. Well that depends on your actual problem

Comment: Why do you think that it isn't "_appropriate_"?

Comment: @Dusteh I've added my code. Will that be OK?

Comment: Well the presented code doesn't show anything meaningful. You simply have a map with a key which is also added to a map value inside a queue -
 but what's the purpose? Tell us what problem you are trying to solve. The code itself is valid but in this form makes little sense.

Comment: @Dusteh Actually, this is just part of my project. And I've found that the problem I met did not result from the way I use map. Thanks a lot anyway.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to know if it's proper to use another type of container, for example, queue, as value of a map.

Yes. It is an appropriate way to use a map.

The value type can be any type that is assignable. `std::queue` and other containers are assignable. The type must also be comparable using the provided `Compare` argument. Standard containers are comparable by the default `std::less`.

As pointed out in the comments, there are further requirements depending on which member functions you use. All standard containers satisfy them all unless there is an exception that I've missed.

---

For those who are wondering, what is an appropriate way to use a map with container values, I recommend a mental exercise:

First imagine a case where you would need a container. I use `std::string` in this example. You might use `std::string` to represent a sentence of English for example.

Second, imagine a case where you would like to associate certain keys with values. This is what the map container can be used for.

Third, imagine a case where the values of the map are container objects. For example, you might have a map of strings where a language code is mapped to a sentence in the corresponding language. This is an appropriate use of map of containers (a map of strings in particular).

I used string in this example, but it applies to other containers as well, such as queues.

Comment: More like a comment

Comment: @P0W no. A comment would be like "Did you mean something else?". The correct answer to the question is "Yes". The question may be simple, but that doesn't mean it can't be answered.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110165/232397 . And before you ask, I didn't downvote *yet* !

Comment: The value may also need to be default-constructible and/or emplace-constructible (eg. if you use `operator[]`) - queue meets those requirements too, of course.

Comment: @P0W And I hadn't assumed that you had ;) I'm relieved to find out that my point of view is at least shared by an answer with a positive score in that meta question, even if it isn't the most popular point of view.

Answer (score 0):

Sure:

```
#include <queue>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using std::string

std::map<string, std::queue<string>> mymap;
```

Then you can write

```
mymap["aaa"].push("bbb");
```

Basically, a `map` is another way to give your objects an extra identifier.

Answer (score 0):

The question doesn't have enough information in to say a solid yes or no (you may have picked that up from the comments); so the best that can be said is "Maybe".

The fact that you feel you need to ask suggests that you've got second thoughts about your design.  If you have second thoughts about your design it's usually worth stopping and getting that right before you write any more code.

If, for example, you find yourself thinking about creating a dozen maps with the same keys; then you'd probably be better off creating a single object that wraps all the values.

If on the other hand you just want a map of string to queue of strings ... then why would you do anything else!

Comment: I've edited my question. Will my code be OK? Actually, the code is just part of my project, and I have to write it both with c and with c++.

Comment: Yes, it's a little strange that you do a strcpy when you could just do `std::string tmp("Hello World")` but it'll work just fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help.